# Ninject ignoring [Inject] attribute

Tags: ninject

I've got a setup with Ninject and NHibernate like this. Now, if I have this scenario..

```cs
class HomeController : Controller
{
 [Inject]
 public ISession Session { get; set; }

}
```

This works properly.

But if I make another class ...

```cs
class QueryObject
{
 [Inject]
 public ISession Session { get; set; }
}

// .. somewhere else in my program.
var test = new QueryObject().Execute();
```

The ISession is null! This is not just with ISession, it is with anything I try to inject.

Here is my SessionModule:

```cs
public class SessionModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ISessionFactory>()
            .ToMethod(c => CreateSessionFactory())
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(c => OpenSession())
            .InRequestScope()
            .OnActivation(session =>
            {
                session.BeginTransaction();
                session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Commit;
            })
            .OnDeactivation(session =>
            {
                if (session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        session.Transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        session.Transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new <see cref="NHibernate.ISessionFactory"/> to connect to a database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A constructed and mapped <see cref="NHibernate.ISessionFactory"/>.
    /// </returns>
    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            sessionFactory = Persistence.SessionFactory.Map
                (System.Web.Configuration
                    .WebConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["Local"]
                    .ConnectionString
                );
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Open a new <see cref="NHibernate.ISession"/> from a <see cref="NHibernate.ISessionFactory"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A new <see cref="NHibernate.ISession"/>.
    /// </returns>
    private static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        // check to see if we even have a session factory to get a session from
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            CreateSessionFactory();

        // open a new session from the factory if there is no current one
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Comment: NB in general a query object (as with entities in general) shouldnt have such dependencies in the first place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's working for controllers because you're instantiating them with Ninject (via the controller factory).

When you're doing `new QueryObject().Execute();` your're not using Ninject to instantiate your QueryObject. The .NET framework itself has no knowledge of injecting properties.

You need to use the Ninject Kernel to resolve your QueryObject. Something like this should do it:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SessionModule());
var queryObject = kernel.Get<QueryObject>();
queryObject.Execute();
```

The kernel will then instantiate a new QueryObject with all dependencies properly set.

For this to work, you'll have to register the QueryObject:

```
Bind<QueryObject>().ToSelf();
```

This tells Ninject to always return a instance of an QueryObject when you're doing `kernel.Get<QueryObject>();`

This is done in your `SessionModule`.

I recommend reading [Modules and the Kernel](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20and%20the%20Kernel) from the docs. ≈

Comment: Is there a way to design a Non Service Locator pattern to have Ninject include things flagged with, say `IInject` in its injection?

Comment: Yes, make sure everythings instantiated with Ninject from the beginning. Where are you using your QueryObject?

Comment: Nowhere, yet. I was trying to see if I could even get it to work before I started making anything real with it. I'm trying to design a Bus service/Message Handler system instead of a Repository pattern by encapsulating queries and commands for performance granularity. Unfortunately this won't work if I have to rely on a service locator pattern. And I read the entire Ninject docs already, it didn't really elude to this.

Comment: There should not be a need for a service locator here. As long as you make sure Ninject instantiate your dependencies. I recommend using constructor injection. It's easier to help if you're able to show some code.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can't do what I want with Ninject. I'm going to have to think of a different approach.

Comment: Constructor injection isn't an option for it, unfortunately. There isn't any other code that would be relevant to this example.

Comment: Unfortunately the example you gave is not sufficient for what I need to do. To do it, I would need a static reference to `IKernel`, which is only provided if I go with a pure Service Locator pattern and create a static property, and everytime I do that, I get yelled at by my other teammates.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up what was going wrong for me. I'm not sure how to approach it, now, though. I can't just keep a static reference to the `IKernel`, but I need to make sure the classes are constructed by Ninject when called... and I can't pass them through constructors.

Comment: @alexn: Those docs are mothballed. The equivalent up to date on is is https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel - oif you feel anything hgas been lost in the port, please point it out. @Ian Davis @Remo Gloor, any way those docs can disappear or be marked way out of date / the codeplex site be deleted ?

Comment: No, the docs were fine. I just misunderstood. alexn's answer was correct and flawless, my approach and intention is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following if you want to create the object yourself:

```
class QueryObject
{
  [Inject]
  public ISession Session { get; set; }
}

// .. somewhere else in my program.
var test = new QueryObject();
kernel.Inject(test);
```

Ninject will then try to fulfil your dependencies.

Comment: And also, just a thing to be aware of with properties and the Inject attribute, Ninject cannot do the binding if the property is private.

Comment: Not 100% correct. By default it does not inject for privates but you can enable it on the ninject settings